# How to extract an early return into a method shared by multiple controllers?

Tags: java

I have multiple methods in multiple Java controllers that will check (before continuing) if the authenticated user ID (from the User Principle) matches the user ID sent in the HTTP request. If the 2 do not match, then the controller will return a ResponseEntity with status code UNAUTHORIZED. The problem is that these number of lines are duplicated throughout the Java Controllers. Is there any way to extract these into a class method that is shared by all of these controllers? Here is an example in one controller:

```
@PostMapping("results")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<?> results(
        Authentication authentication,
        @RequestBody ResultsRequest request
) {
    try {
        User user = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
        Long userId = request.getUserId();
        if (isNull(user) || !user.getId().equals(userId)) {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).body(Map.of(
                    SUCCESS, false,
                    ERROR, ErrorCode.RETRIEVING_ANOTHER_USER_DATA_PROHIBITED.getMessage()
            ));
        }
        // this is the happy path - continue with the request
        return resultsService.getResults(userId);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        LOGGER.warn(ErrorCode.ERROR_GETTING_RESULTS.getMessage(), e);
    }
    return ResponseEntity.ok(List.of());
}
```

This is currently present in dozens of files. So the lines I would like to extract are

```
User user = (User) authentication.getPrincipal();
Long userId = request.getUserId();
if (isNull(user) || !user.getId().equals(userId)) {
    return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED).body(Map.of(
            SUCCESS, false,
            ERROR, ErrorCode.RETRIEVING_ANOTHER_USER_DATA_PROHIBITED.getMessage()
    ));
}
```

But because this is a **conditional return** (i.e. will not always return, or **should not return in normal circumstances**) I'm not sure how to extract this to another class/method.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: Java does not have non-local returns (i.e. returning from one method inside another). You will have to signal the need to return in another way. For example, your extracted method could return the Response it does now, or `null` for the happy path. Then in each of your controllers, check for null and return based on that.

Comment: For a more "frame challenge" type answer, you shouldn't be doing this check inside your controllers in the first place. It should be in a filter, which then fixes the duplicate code as well. Simply apply the filter to all relevant endpoints before the controller is even called.

Comment: @Jorn Ah of course, this is what I was looking for. Or maybe implementing a HandlerInterceptor on all controllers... thanks

Comment: @Jorn if you have the time to provide an example of implementing  such filter that would be great , I have a similar problem scenario but mine is that the user tries to fetch data that does not belong to him, so I would need to fetch the data first then check if the user id matches the id data related to